# Make plane fold in curve (arc) while conserving its length

Tags: bones, bezier-curves

I want to fold a plane such that it forms an arc (curved plane). I initially used bevel modifier, but the problem is the plane length is not conserved.

[image: Original]
[image: Bevel]

You can see that the length is shorten after beveling. I want to fold the plane such that the plane length is conserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say length should be "conserved," do you mean this in an approximate sense or a mathematically strict sense?  Doing it in a strict sense might be more difficult.

I am a little confused when you are talking about using a bevel modifier but you're showing the use of an armature.  You could certainly use them together, but why not simply parent the plane to the bones of your armature with weight paints to control the influence of each bone in a graduated/curved fashion?

[image: folded paper]

For this example I used linear gradient weight paints for each bone:

[image: weight paint for bone 1]

[image: weight paint for bone 2]

I am sure you could tweak the gradients to get the curvature more to your liking.

But maybe this isn't what you had in mind?